# ClassCastException in between equal classes Wildfly 10

Tags: java, connection, wrapper, wildfly, classcastexception

I am Creating a RESTful application and I am having trouble making a conversion for a new connection.
My application server is Wildfly 10.0.

**DataSource and Driver in standalone-full.xml:**

```
<datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/PostgreDS" pool-name="PostgreDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
    <connection-url>jdbc:postgresql://192.168.0.112:5432/bdns</connection-url>
    <driver>postgresql</driver>
    <transaction-isolation>TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED</transaction-isolation>
    <pool>
        <min-pool-size>10</min-pool-size>
        <max-pool-size>40</max-pool-size>
        <prefill>true</prefill>
    </pool>
    <security>
        <user-name>sa</user-name>
        <password>000000</password>
    </security>
    <statement>
        <prepared-statement-cache-size>32</prepared-statement-cache-size>
        <share-prepared-statements>true</share-prepared-statements>
    </statement>
</datasource>
<drivers>
    <driver name="postgresql" module="org.postgresql">
        <xa-datasource-class>org.postgresql.xa.PGXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
    </driver>
</drivers>
```

**Java code ConnectionMng.java:**

```
package dao;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.jdk7.WrappedConnectionJDK7;
import org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection;

public class ConnectionMng {
    private DataSource ds;

    private ConnectionMng() throws NamingException {
        this.ds = (DataSource)new InitialContext().lookup("java:jboss/datasources/PostgreDS");
    }

    public PgConnection getPgConnection() throws SQLException {
        WrappedConnectionJDK7 wrappedConn = (WrappedConnectionJDK7)ds.getConnection();
        Connection underlyingConn = wrappedConn.getUnderlyingConnection(); 
        return (PgConnection)underlyingConn;
    }
}
```

**Exception occurred:**

```
ClassCastException: org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.jdk7.WrappedConnectionJDK7 cannot be cast to org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.jdk7.WrappedConnectionJDK7
```

**pom.xml:**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>Core</groupId>
<artifactId>Core</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>Core</name>
<description>Core</description>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <javac.target>1.8</javac.target>
    <postgresql.enforce.jdk.version>[1.7,1.8)</postgresql.enforce.jdk.version>
</properties>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
        <artifactId>wildfly-connector</artifactId>
        <version>10.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
        <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.junrar</groupId>
        <artifactId>junrar</artifactId>
        <version>0.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.zeroturnaround</groupId>
        <artifactId>zt-zip</artifactId>
        <version>1.9</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: so what type Object is being returned from `ds.getConnection()` ?

Comment: @ScaryWombat
Connection the application server yes. But I need the type PgConnection.

Comment: It looks like the ironjacamar-jars are packaged in your WEB-INF-lib directory, maybe due to the wildfly-connector-dependency.  So you've got two classes of  WrappedConnectionJDK7 : one from lib-directory and one from the modules-directory of the wildfly

Comment: @JanPiel What can I do to fix?

Comment: Why don't you mark your *wildfly-connector* dependency as **provided**? WildFly already has it. There's no need for you to pack it with your application.

Comment: I would try this: You can also handle the dependencies with the MANISFEST.MF. So for example remove the maven-dependency wildfly-connector from your pom and add following entry in the MANIFEST.MF : Dependencies: org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters     In eclipse with jboss-tools now the WrappedConnectionJDK7 should be solved by the class from jar in the modules-directory. During deployment, the dependency is also loaded by scanning the MANIFEST.MF. @aribeiro: You're right, but without the MANIFEST-entry, I think there occur a ClassNotFoundException during deployment

Comment: Try also a look at this  :  https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Class+Loading+in+WildFly

Comment: @JanPiel, when you establish a dependency as *provided* Maven binds it to the classpath but does not package it with your application. How come will it result on a CNFE if the container is providing it?

Comment: @aribeiro  Most of the modules of the Wildfly are not provided automatically. A JEE6-Project gets the JEE6-Spec automatic and so on. But the ironjacamar-JCA-Impl(not the spec) is not loaded by default. As I think  -   I use Wildfly 8, not 10, maybe it changed. You have to tell the wildfly-deployer, what classes/modules to load, either by a MANIFEST-entry or by a jboss-deployment-structure.xml

Comment: @JanPiel, you're definitely right. Whether its WildFly 8 or WildFly 10 the behavior is the same: one needs to trigger the JCA-subsystem explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer from aribeiro is the right answer: A jar, packaged by the build-tool(Maven) is in the lib-directory of the war and conflicts with the wildfly-Classloader.

Additional,here is a generic solution for the following issue:

- you've got a JBoss 7 AS or a Wildfly AS
- You work with Eclipse JBoss Tools
- you deploy an EAR or a WAR, lib-Folder is packed by build-tool like Maven
- there occurs an error like this: examplepackage.ExcampleClass cannot be cast to examplepackage.ExcampleClass

Mostly it happens, when you leave the Java EE-Spec and use JBoss/Wildfly-specific modules, ironjacamar, jsf-impl and so on. Maven puts the required jars in the lib-directory. But the Jars are already in the module-directory of the AS. According to my experience, the `ClassCastException` occurs for this reason.

You must then remove the jar from the lib-directory, in maven by declaring the dependency as provided.

Tell the JBoss/Wildfly-Classloader, where to find the class. This can be done by:

- Either add a dependency to the `MANIFEST.MF` of the project. Eclipse-JBoss-Tools loads the class from the Server-Enviroment, so you can remove the dependency from the pom. In your case:

  ```
  Dependencies: org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters
  ```
- Or you use the `jboss-deployment-structure.xml`, then you can load the class with Maven, but declare it as provided

  ```
  <dependencies>
      <module name="org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters" />
  </dependencies>
  ```

See also https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Class+Loading+in+WildFly

Answer (score 2):

Clearly, as already stated, you're having a classloader issue due to a dependency clash.

To solve it, you should mark your *wildfly-connector* dependency as **provided**.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
    <artifactId>wildfly-connector</artifactId>
    <version>10.0.0.Final</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

WildFly already contains the JAR. If you go to the following folder you can find it:

```
<wildfly-10.0.0.Final-dir>\modules\system\layers\base\org\jboss\as\connector\main
```

There's no need for you to pack it with your application.

Nevertheless, as stated on [WildFly 10's Implicit module dependencies for deployments](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/Implicit+module+dependencies+for+deployments), one needs to trigger the JCA sub-system explicitly. For that, one can make use of *jboss-deployment-structure.xml* with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters" slot="main"/>            
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Then, add your *jboss-deployment-structure.xml* to the *WEB-INF* folder of your WAR.